# How to style more then one image in CSS

Tags: html, css

So ive been trying it for 1 hour, I already tried every solution already posted here regarding this problem,

I have a logo which I named img in CSS, and as you can see in a picture I want to edit “Font Awesome” image in CSS, but it wont work, I tried:

```
CSS:

.second {
float: right;
opacity: 0.5;
}

HTML:

<div class=“second”>
<img src=
"https://www.vectorlogo.zone/
logos/
font-awesome/
font-awesome-card.png">
</div>
```

I tried just adding class=“” to HTML code and that didnt worked either, maybe its thats the code is inside .box code, if I have to post whole code Ill do it, cheers, hoping for solution

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCHWS.png)

Comment: Post your code so we can understand more the structure of what you want to do

Comment: Does your img src have linebreaks (enters)?

Comment: Cause it looks like it the way you formatted your code

Comment: You're using typographical quotes (`“…”`) in your code. That's not going to work. You need to use straight ASCII quotes (`"…"`).

Answer (score 0):

`<img class="second" src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/font-awesome/font-awesome-card.png">`

CSS :

`.second {
float: right;
opacity: 0.5;
}`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fz4nx1k/49/)

Comment: It doesnt work, I really think it has something with img { } in css that im using for logo, its like it changing every picture on website, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use this:

css:

```
.second img {
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

if that doesn't work maybe use an id?

html:

```
 <div id=“second”>
<img src=
"https://www.vectorlogo.zone/
logos/
font-awesome/
font-awesome-card.png">
</div>
```

css:

```
#second img {
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: No luck, should I just get out logo of the img tag? This is my css code for image:  img {
    width: 146px;
    height: auto;
    position: center;
    opacity: 0.5;
} So I think that by this tag every image with img is affected, isnt it?

Comment: @YoungSquad yes, this will affect all images on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with HTML from Hamed Basha:

```
<img class="imagelogo" src="https://www.vectorlogo.zone/logos/fontawesome/font-awesome-card.png">
```

And this css:

```
img {
....
}

img .imagelogo {
....
{
```

Thanks guys